# Is it possible to import only Ajax method from jQuery with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I'm working with Webpack and am trying to figure out if it is possible to only import jQuery's Ajax functionality using named module imports or some other method.

After I `npm install jquery --save`

If I try to import only deferred, it appears successful:

`import { Deferred} from 'jquery'; // returns the $.deferred method`

but

`import { Ajax } from 'jquery'; // returns undefined`

Is there a named export for Deferred but not Ajax?

Thanks for any help. I'm open to any npm wizardry but don't want to use bower. I haven't needed it yet and would rather just import the whole jQuery library using NPM than bring in all that for a single module.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can just require certain features. [This blog post shows you how.](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/jquery-using-only-what-you-need/)

> The good news is, as of jQuery 2.1, jQuery uses AMD to organize its dependencies internally. This means you can use AMD to load individual pieces of jQuery, and not the whole library.

Bower is super simple - its nearly the same as NPM but for browser stuff instead of server stuff. And you see it all over the place, I'm sure you can get some functionality out of it. You just use the command line to install your stuff instead of downloading and linking.

I would go for native XHR stuff. Its simpler than people make it out to be. Check out [this link](http://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/ajax/) for some comparison between jQuery and native ajax.

jQuery is very handy, but I feel like it should be the alternative to doing things native, not the other way around.